# ¿Qué sucede ante una pregunta ya planteada pero cuya respuesta esta obsoleta?

Tags: discusión, respuesta

La cosa es simple, con el paso del tiempo se acumulan preguntas y respuestas, estas son validas en el momento que se formulan pero al avanzar las versiones del lenguaje la pregunta, la respuesta o ambas dejan de ser validas.

¿que se hace en estos casos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En la pregunta planteas varios casos y para cada uno habría una respuesta diferente. Depende de la pregunta y de cómo de funcional sea la respuesta.

Que una pregunta sea sobre una versión antigua de un lenguaje o herramienta, no significa que esté obsoleta. Hay muchos casos (especialmente en ambientes corporativos) en los que las versiones antiguas de lenguaje/software son lo normal y algo que no puede evitarse.

En ese sentido, **si en la pregunta se especifica una versión** antigua y tiene soluciones para esa versión, aunque aparezca una nueva versión con una manera más moderna y mejor de solucionar el problema. Tanto la pregunta como la respuesta no estarían obsoletas.

Por ejemplo: si la pregunta es sobre cómo hacer algo en Python 3 y tiene una respuesta válida, pero luego en Python 4 se hace de otra manera. Si la pregunta indica específicamente Python 3, la respuesta sería correcta a pesar de ser obsoleta. (En parte porque la pregunta también estaría "obsoleta").

Ahora, **si la pregunta no especifica ninguna versión** y en versiones más modernas  existe una nueva manera de solucionar la pregunta con herramientas más adecuadas, deberíamos plantearnos otra cosa: ¿la manera especificada en la respuesta sigue funcionando?

En cualquier caso, podría editarse la respuesta para dejar una nota/comentario al respecto "Esta es una manera *antigua* de hacer las cosas..." Pero no cambiaría el contenido de la respuesta en sí (cambiarla para añadir un nuevo método sería una edición en contra de la intención del autor).

**Si la respuesta seguiría funcionando, aunque no sea ideal**, creo que con el comentario/nota sería suficiente. Al fin y al cabo, la respuesta seguiría funcionando aunque no sea la mejor.

**Si la respuesta no seguiría funcionando**, entonces es una respuesta obsoleta que realmente ya no aporta más. Podrías votar negativo, dejarle una nota al autor, o actuar de la manera que consideres apropiada. (Siempre teniendo en cuenta que al otro lado del teclado va a haber una persona que invirtió tiempo en escribir una respuesta).

Comment: Me gusta los casos que has mencionado. Aunque lo mencionas quizás habría que hacer mayor énfasis en que si una pregunta es sobre un lenguaje o tecnología obsoletos (entiéndase que existe otros mas recientes) no implica que las respuestas lo sean, dependerá de cada caso en particular.

Comment: Esta deberia ser la respuesta aceptada...

Comment: Esta pregunta esta respondida en stackmeta y sugieren la utilizacion de bounties.

Comment: @MacGyver ¿Puedes enlazar la pregunta de MSE? Sé que una pregunta con recompensa no se puede cerrar, pero los moderadores tienen poder para devolver la recompensa y cerrarla si no se ajusta a la temática/formato del sitio.

Comment: Seguro @AlvaroMontoro, la recuerdo porque la hice y hasta me la marcaron como duplicada :D Por eso comente! En realidad creo que lo que sugieren es que, aunque este cerrada y respondida, generar una bounty para visualizarla mejor. Claro que alla tenemos el inconveniente de los duplicados infinitos que casi hasta hacen imposible una busqueda decente.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287447/its-wrong-making-a-new-question-of-an-older-question-looking-for-updated-answer

Comment: @MacGyver perdón. He estado contestando a otras preguntas y me he confundido. Creía que estaba en la pregunta sobre preguntas basadas en opiniones. Poner una recompensa es una gran idea para atraer nuevas respuestas más actualizadas.

Comment: Me encanta lo que han hecho aca, pero creo que el level es mas bajo, no se por que! Asi que seguire estando por alla, ya que no participo tanto ! abrazos

Comment: No creo que el nivel medio sea más bajo. Pero es más fácil obtener ayuda en el sitio en inglés. Hay muchos más usuarios y es más fácil encontrar a uno que sepa y esté dispuesto a ayudar. Si te quedas con nosotros y participas, estarás ayudando a subir el nivel del sitio ;)

Answer (score 7):

Lo dejé como comentario, pero opino que esto debería tener mucha más visualización.

Es importante aclarar que una respuesta obsoleta, no es una mala respuesta, ni es una respuesta errónea. Es una respuesta que con el paso del tiempo y los cambios de tecnología, va quedando desactualizada. Por lo tanto, la misma no debería ser votada negativamente.

Cuando se encuentra una respuesta así, lo mejor es marcarla editándola, o dejándole un comentario al autor, aclarando la situación por lo cual la respuesta es obsoleta, y luego de ello, contestar o atraer la atención hacia la pregunta para agregar una respuesta más actual.

Si esto lo hace el autor original de la respuesta, editando la misma, y dejando todas las versiones, mucho mejor.

Si no, agregar otra respuesta aclarando para qué versión es adecuada, es válido y coherente con la forma de manejarse del sitio.

No se debería votar negativamente la respuesta obsoleta. En su momento no era obsoleta, es una buena respuesta, pero para la tecnología actual no sirve.

Por lo tanto si encuentras una respuesta obsoleta, encárgate de alguna forma de que se actualice, y no penalices al usuario que se tomó el trabajo en su momento de contestarla!

Comment: y de hecho  en respuestas de stackoverflow en ingles existen comentarios "funciona para la version x.y", "version x.z obsoleta" , [aqui un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280007/retrieving-a-foreign-key-value-with-django-rest-framework-serializers/17293090#comment90896613_17293090)

Comment: @JackNavaRow y de hecho [yo hice lo de agregar una respuesta en una pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49969260/4914734) en [so] :D

Comment: Quizás primero deberíamos decir que entendemos por "respuesta obsoleta"

Answer (score -3):

Uno de los criterios de votación incluidos en los lineamientos del sitio es el de la utilidad de la publicación, si la publicación es útil desde un punto de vista práctico, se vota positivo, si no lo es se vota negativo.

En el caso de una respuesta obsoleta, esta no es útil.

Nótese que estoy hablando desde un punto de vista práctico, no desde un vista histórico y me refiero a respuesta obsoletas por completo.

Podrías dejar un comentario para que el autor la actualice o si la actualización es simple, hacerla tu mismo. Si existen otras respuestas que están actualizadas, vota la respuesta obsoleta negativo para que eventualmente se mueva hacia abajo en la vista por votos y las respuestas actualizadas vótalas positivo para que se muevan hacia arriba.

---

Como lo mencioné en un comentario, viejo no significa obsoleto. Tampoco el que exista una nueva versión de un lenguaje determinado significa que las versiones anteriores están obsoletas.

Una respuesta sería obsoleta si hablara de una solución o característica que ya ha cambiado de tal forma que ya no se puede usar. Por ejemplo,  una respuesta que sugiere usar el Servicio UiApp de Google Apps Script es obsoleta porque dicho servicio ha sido "deprecated" (retirado) y hoy día nadie lo puede usar y por  lo tanto, desde un punto de vista práctico, no es útil.

Por otro lado, una respuesta que hablara sobre funciones anónimas en JavaScript alguien podría argumentar que es obsoleta porque ahora existen las funciones flecha y que serían una mejor opción para responder la pregunta. En este caso las funciones anónimas siguen siendo parte de la especificación y se pueden seguir usando, así que la respuesta en cuestión no sería obsoleta porque algunos podría preferir seguir usando funciones anónimas en lugar de funciones flecha como sería el caso de código mantenido por un equipo de desarrolladores donde antes de introducir una "novedad" primero se quisiera certificar a los miembros del equipo en dicha "novedad".

No confundamos la obselecencia de un lenguaje o equipo de lo que seria de una respuesta.

Hoy día Windows XP está "obsoleto" pero se sigue utilizando. Visual Fox ya no se vende pero se sigue usando. Las respuestas a este tipo de preguntas mientras sean útiles deberían votarse positivo, no votarse negativo por tratar de sistemas operativos o manejadores de bases de datos "obsoletos".

En nuestro caso, el sitio se lanzó en el 2016. Mientras las respuestas de ese año sigan siendo útiles, deberían votarse positivo.

---

Relacionado SE Meta

- [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11705/289691)
- [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/289691)

Comment: En realidad votar negativo una respuesta "obsoleta" no creo que sea la mejor idea. Mejor editarla y aclarar las versiones para la cual la respuesta es valida, y agregar o conseguir una respuesta para una version mas actualizada. Que haya quedado vieja, no quiere decir que sea mala. Ojo con eso.

Comment: @gbianchi Ni el AP ni yo hemos dicho que lo viejo sea obsoleto, ni que por ser viejo deba ser votado negativo. He encontrado respuestas recientes que proponen cosas obsoletas así como respuestas viejas que siguen siendo útiles hoy día. Por otro lado también menciono que otras a hacer no sólo el votar negativo. :)

Comment: Ruben, [tengo un comentario de que actualice mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113005/error-con-validaci%c3%b3n-de-solo-n%c3%bameros-en-firefox/113012#comment254756_113012) una vez que estuvo aceptada y dio problema,el usuario me comento que en firefox tiene problemas(casualmente tu) , no marcaron -1

Comment: @JackNavaRow Perdón, inmediatamente iré a marcar -1 :P

Comment: cuando dejastes el comentario, la edite para que funcionara, es lo que me falto agregar al comentario anterior, y si consideras que no es util adelante

Comment: Quizás no te marqué negativo porque como mencionas se mencionó que el problema ocurre en un navegador específico, no por ello la respuesta era obsoleta, simplemente no contemplaba un navegador que rara vez uso. Que bueno que te animaste a mejorar tu pregunta.